# Is it necessary to use load() twice to append same file to two different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file that have two sections (`#container` and `#area`) and I want to use `load()` to place them in two different elements on the document. I want to make sure if it's necessary to use two `load()` to place each of them into separate areas. Can I do it all in one load?

jQuery:

```
$('#results').on('click','.category_select',function (e) {
   var source = $(this).data('source');

   $("#results").load(''+source+' #container',function(){
   });

   $("#featuredtable").load(''+source+' #area',function(){
   });

});
```

File HTML

```
<div id='container'>bbbbbbb</div>
<div id='area'>aaaaaaa</div>
```

Document HTML

```
<div class='category_select'>Click</div>
<div id='result'></div>
<div id='featuredtable'></div>
```

Comment: why don't use `$.get()` and do the html processing yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't use `$.get()` and do the html processing yourself, like

```
$('#results').on('click', '.category_select', function (e) {
    var source = $(this).data('source');

    $.get(source, function (html) {
        var $html = $(html);
        $("#results").empty().append($html.find('#container'));
        $("#featuredtable").empty().append($html.find('#area'));
    })
});
```

*Note: not tested*

Comment: Yeah,that seems to be the solution

Comment: Why `.empty().append(`? Why not just `.html(`, that will replace the old content of the element.

Comment: @Niklas yes... but since the [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) documentation does not say about a version that takes a jQuery object, I prefer not to use it like that

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I've tested it. But it isn't working. It can't find the load file's selectors. Please check this [Example](http://cheapgamessales.com/1.php)

Comment: @RedGiant it is because of the html format used... in your case `$html` directly contains both `#results` and `#featuedtable` elements(they are not descendants of the elements referred by `$html`) so you cannot use `.find()`, you need to use `.filter()` instead. If you had a structure like `<div><div id='container'>bbbbbbb</div>
<div id='area'>aaaaaaa</div></div>` then `.find()` will work

Comment: @ArunPJohny Ah, of course. You're adding the jQuery Objects, not their content as a string. My bad!

Comment: @Niklas but ` $("#results").html($html.find('#container'));` works... just that I normally doesn't use that